# Update insert data in hive through pyspark

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have data which keeps on changing in source. I am pulling that data through sqoop but as the volume is large i cannot keep it as daily truncate load. I want to append the data but the logic should be update and insert. If a record is updating in source by deleting the previous same record, same should be done in hive i.e. old record should be deleted and new one should be inserted/updated.
Below is one such example.

[image]

After some time say 30 mins, the data is updated like this:

[image]

Now, my hive table picked up original record and after some time picked the updated record but inserted it as a different row.

[image]

I want the data to be reflected same as that it is in source without overwriting my table.
(Pyspark code is recommended)

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: You are only pulling new and updated records, **How you are identifying delta records**? And whats the volume of updated records?

Comment: I have a timestamp column in source which gets updated when record is changed/updated, and through sqoop incremental logic I'm pulling them in hive as sqoop always stores last incremental value in metadata. Volume of updated record is almost 8-10 lakhs per day. It includes both, updated + new entries.

Comment: You may want to look at alternative storage formats (HBase, Kudu) since plain HDFS doesn't have a concept of update.

Answer (score 0):

Not providing a query but giving an idea how you can achieve this:
Create a staging table between source and your actual hive table which will have all the records (inserts as well as updates).

To get the actual hive table, use rank function something like:

```
rank() over (partition by id order by ingested_ts desc) as rnk
---
---
where rnk = 1
```

[image]

Note: Depending on your data volumes, hive_staging table might grow, so you need to add partitions/buckets accordingly.

Comment: Exactly what i am doing right now, but the issue is with large volume of data. When i am creating my final hive table after ranking, the total data comes out to be approx 70-80 cr. And loading such data in hive takes almost 1-2 hours which I don't want. I want this to be completed in 5-10 mins. Like exactly how upsert works. Also, i want to schedule it every 1 hour. So if data loading itself takes 1 hour, i can't do ranking.

Comment: How large is your cluster? Also, why don't you use acid properties in Hive which is exactly meant for these use cases.

Comment: can you elaborate how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more column in your source as last_modified and also in hive as last_load, and when next time you are  uploading ,you can specify two condition on  (id column in source and id column in hive) and (last_modified of source table and last_update of hive column).